# Modelbuilder Join

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, attribute-joins, iterator

Trying to do an iterate with a join to a table to create a new feature class.

The output has the spatial data but with none of the fields of the join making it. 
I think that I have the problem sourced, but have no idea how to resolve it. If you look at the code block below, you will see a feature class named "...L8.shp" that is locked in memory and won't leave. Each iteration, that feature class is there messing me up (at least I think). The tool is supposed to take the input, in this case "...S11s.shp", join its MKEY to the UKEY of tables4elim and take all of the tables4elim fields. Why this L8 is locked in I have no idea and need it gone so that I can get my results!!

```
Executing (Feature Class to Feature Class (2)): FeatureClassToFeatureClass Multiunion_Multiunion_S11_Layer 

\\silver\clients\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Eliminate TSA_PE_Multiunion_S11s.shp 

# "MKey "MKey" true true false 9 Long 0 9 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,MKEY_L8.MKey,-1,-1;AreaHA "AreaHA" true true false 19 Double 0 0 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,MKEY_L8.AreaHA,-1,-1;UKEY "UKEY" true true false 19 Double 10 18 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,tables4elim.UKEY,-1,-1;POLY_NUM "POLY_NUM" true true false 10 Double 0 10 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,tables4elim.POLY_NUM,-1,-1;BLOCKS "BLOCKS" true true false 25 Text 0 0 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,tables4elim.BLOCKS,-1,-1;F_DEL "F_DEL" true true false 12 Text 0 0 ,First,#,

G:\ALPAC\Projects\P747\3_Landbase\LB1\Coverage_World\MultiUnion\Eliminate\MKEY_L8.shp

,tables4elim.F_DEL,-1,-1" #
```

[image]

Comment: I now have doubts that this is my problem, it may still be, but other ideas are welcome

Comment: Perhaps get rid of the field map, it may be constricting the joined fields out. What is the value of 'maintain fully qualified'?

Comment: I have tried removing the field map to no avail. The value is false.

Comment: Do you have duplicate field names? i.e. fields that exist in the join *from* feature class and also in the join *to* table.

Comment: No. 
I am currently trying to convert this to Python and in some quick tests, the joins work in the script. So something is not communicating correctly in Modelbuilder. I will be posting my python script for it shortly on here as I cannot get field mapping to work inside of my feature class to feature class.